# CSS: Handle overflow using the child element

Tags: css, overflow

I have an html code in this architecture:

```
<div id="container">
    ... some divs ...
    <div id="results">
        ... some content ...
    </div>
</div>
```

the content written in the **results** changes and sometimes the **results**' height goes past the **container**'s bottom. I want the **results** the handle the overflow with scrollbars not the **container** but I can't seem to fix this. what should I do? I'm open to javascript solutions as long as they're flexible to changes in window size.

note: the **results** div does not have a fixed non-percentage height in CSS and it can't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford to use flexbox you could solve it in the following way (omitted prefixes for brevity's sake):

```
#container {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

#results {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4n3tmbm3/5/

Comment: Thanks, I guess the correct way to handle this problem is using flexbox, I'll implement it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way:

```
#container {overflow: hidden;}
#results {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will do what you want to achieve, let me know if any thing else needed ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have the same problem as fixed height with `max-height`. I don't want to limit the height to absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: auto` on the child & `overflow-y: hidden` on the parent and give a `max-height` if you can't give a fixed height.

```
#container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#results {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I have the same problem as fixed height with `max-height`. I don't want to limit the height to absolute values.